# How to locate diffrent images on a button boundaries

Tags: android, image

i have a Button i want to have - 4 images around its boundaries .
all images exactly the same size .
and they have to be located like in the shown picture.

i don't want to use image button because it can attach only one image, 
please dont offer to create one image on a image button - because i have a dynamic order .

Just tell me how to set the location of images progmatically according to button location .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative layout to implement this!
Also you can make relative layout clickable and set onClickListener on it and make click animation on it! It will work as big button with custom layout on it!

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"   
    android:id="@+id/real_button"
    android:clickable="true">

    <Button android:id="@+id/fake_empty_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp" 
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_above="@+id/fake_empty_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fake_empty_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fake_empty_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fake_empty_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of 200dp make 3 * picture height and istead of 100dp make 1 * picture height!

In the activity:

```
int mX = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.real_button).setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mX % 2 == 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.real_button).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.real_button).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        mX += 1;
    }
};
```

[image: This how it looks like]

Comment: wouldn't above set the entire image above the button ?

Comment: hm... real button is RelativeLayout, button in it is a fake with same height and width as your images, I will edit my answer for better understanding

Comment: I wrote some program which will help to understand better! I will paste it here in some seconds

Comment: Hey i have tried you soulution and the images are outside the button. i want them to be inside the button - what do i have to change ?

Comment: Hi, the button is a relative layout! The images are situated on it! they have to be on this layout! That's why inside of the button they cant be!